# Is it possible to have multiple secrets files in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, secret-key

I'm using a rails app to host multiple sites and am running into a road block with secrets.yml. I have multiple API keys that differ between sites and would like to have a different secrets file in each of my site sub-directories. I want to be able to set the secrets path dynamically, is this possible? Also is it possible to have rails look in multiple paths for secrets at the same time?

Answer (score 3):

`secrets.rb` allows for nesting

```
production:
  site1:
    my_api_key: 'key1'
    my_api_password: 'password1'
  site2:
    my_api_key: 'key2'
    my_api_password: 'password2'
```

You can then load the site_code in an environment variable and do something like this in your code

```
api_key = Rails.application.secrets[ENV['site_code']][:my_api_key]
```